# What is host and controller btsnoop_hci.log?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Inside btnsnoop_hci.log file I am little confused about a host, controller, remote() and LocalHost(). I was digging on google to understand but unable to found the proper documentation which explains it. If you have any idea about btnsnoop_hei.log do share.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The host is the main cpu that runs a Bluetooth stack.

The controller is a separate chip that controls the low level Bluetooth radio.

These two devices (inside the phone) talk with each other usually over UART using the HCI protocol.

A remote controller is the Bluetooth chip in another device that communicates with the local controller over Bluetooth.

Answer (score 4):

In HCI *Host* and *Controller* both are logical entities and related to layers of Bluetooth protocols executed on the same device. Generally *Host* layers are executed on application processor or microcontroller and *Controller* layers are executed on Bluetooth chip attached to it.
Words *remote* and *localhost* are about different devices. Possibly they are Wireshark specific (and connected to BT MAC addresses). I do not remember them in Frontline Sodera software.